# Persistent CSRF token is safe/secure?

Tags: php, security, token, csrf

my previous algorithm for my CSRF token is using `password_hash()`, and this is multi-tab and cross-tab friendly. My only problem is that, when I start profiling my codes using `kCacheGrind`, this function is eating most of the time which is `Incl. = 87.1` & `Self = 87.11`, I am not an expert in profiling but `KCacheGrind` said that I should focus with a high `Self` time. So I searched here, I saw `ThiefMaster's` answer and said that;

> You could simply use a token which is persistent for the current
>   session or even the user (e.g. a hash of the hash of the user's
>   password) and cannot be determined by a third party (using a hash of
>   the user's IP is bad for example).
>
> Then you don't have to store possibly tons of generated tokens and
>   unless the session expires (which would probably require the user to
>   login again anyway) the user can use as many tabs as he wants.

Is using a persistent CSRF token safe/secure?

what do I need to do to make a persistent CSRF token safe/secure?

Comment: `multitab and crosstab enable` grammar ?

Comment: it is *less* secure than a non-persistent token. why not focus your efforts on using something other than `password_hash()`? Try `random_bytes`, `mcrypt_create_iv`, `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` or even `hash`

Comment: My previous algo before `password_hash()` is using `random_bytes`, problem is that it is not multi-tab and cross-tab friendly.

Comment: I would recommend using more than username, you should include the form/page name with username, it will be persistant for the same form/page and user, but different for every form/page and user, it would be fast and with same security, it will always depend on what are you working. (this is just an example, you can use session id, browser name, salt, etc without needing to save the token)

Comment: @cpatricio, can you show me an example? I can't understand the part of how it will be persistent for the same form/page and user, thank you.

Comment: View: `$token = password_hash($user . $form_name . $browser_name, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)`, Controller: `if(!password_verify($user, $form_name . $browser_name, $token)) error();`, i don't know your code, i expect this is enough to understand, token will be always different (when you reload the page) but you can detect if it was done by the right user in the right form/page.

Comment: Your CSRF does not have to be cryptographically secure, it need only be unique. You might consider generating UUID v4 or v5 (both of which are fast generation) and storing them in a nonce table for verification.

Comment: @cpatricio My problem with `password_hash()` is, it took all of the time when I profiled my page as I also stated in my question, that is why I will change my algorithm to something that is fast, multi-tab/cross-tab friendly and a non-persisent token.

Comment: `$hash = sha1(md5($user . $form));`, this will be persistent, so i would use date and multiple tries to verify the hash (15 minute session, it would be 15 tries if only minutes are different). I tested in my vps, i took 0.014s for 15 tries.